# Leaflet click event and retrieve X,Y and Zoom

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, coordinate-systems

I use leflet with my custom layer for the map.

I implemented a get info function by click on specific location in the map.
I can retrieve `lat` and `lng` of the clicked location but I would to retrieve also `X`, `Y` about Tile coordinates and also the `Zoom` level.

For the zoom level I can use `e.getZoom()` but I can't to retrieve `X` and `Y` coordinates of the point.

Is possible this?

Comment: `X` and `Y` relative to **what**? Screen corner, map corner, CRS origin, tile coordinates...??

Comment: If you want the coordinates of the container element, just check [`containerPoint`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#mouseevent-containerpoint) from leaflet's  `MouseEvent`.  It gives you a Point object with the X and Y values you need.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Sorry, I need the tile coordinates. Same values used to download the specific tile.

Comment: @Safari Please edit your question to reflect that you want tile coordinates.

Comment: Did you figure it out @Safari?

Comment: to get zoom level `e.getZoom()` got error. so i used `map.getZoom()`

Answer (score 1):

I had used lat and lng as `x` and `y` but also used `L.CRS.Simple`

When you draw custom object and insert `x` and `y` you are using coordinates of dot referenced on center of the map.

So in your case I would use `lat` and `lng` as `x` and `y`